# How to pass value from AJAX Javascript to PHP file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to pass value from AJAX file to PHP using below script, but it fail. What is the correct way to do this? Thanks

Sample code as below:

```
function createNewWindow()
{
var newWindowModel = new DHTMLSuite.windowModel({windowsTheme:true,id:'newWindow1',title:'Response Time to Invitation',xPos:130,yPos:400,minWidth:100,minHeight:100 } );
newWindowModel.addTab({ id:'myTab1',htmlElementId:'myTab1',tabTitle:'TAB',textContent:'Send data', contentUrl:'load.php?loadNo:loadNo' } );
var newWindowWidget = new DHTMLSuite.windowWidget(newWindowModel);
newWindowWidget.init();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing values? you mean parameters? if yes:

1. Create an AJAX obj first: `var http = new XMLHttpRequest();`

***The GET method:***

```
var url = "load.php";
var params = "loadNo=loadNo&param=value";
http.open("GET", url+"?"+params, true);
http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(null);
```

***The POST method:***

```
var url = "laod.php";
var params = "loadNo=loadNo&param=value";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
        var x=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    alert(x);
         }
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","load.php?loadNo="+loadNo+"&param="+value,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy way to do a AJAX Request using Jquery

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php", // script path goes here
  type: "GET",
  data: {id : param}, // Parameters go here
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  $("#log").html( msg ); // On success 
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus ); // On failure
});
```